Which deity has been praised the earliest with the "Vidmahe,... Dhimahi... Prachodayath” formula?
A prayer like

Om Kamadevaya Vidmahe Pushpa Baanaya Dhimahi Tanno Ananga Prachodayath.

looks late and derivative.
